# Hide toolbar and increase main screen view height

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am currently facing a problem which that I am having a View with a bottom toolbar.

When I hide the bottom toolbar with this line of codes.

```
self.navigationController.toolbar = YES;
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height + 44)];
```

It does hide up the bottom toolbar but it doesn't do the main view expand part.

And I've also tried to bring the self.view above the self.navigationController.toolbar with this line of code, and it is not working too.

```
 [self.navigationController.view bringSubviewToFront:self.view];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a mistake in line `self.navigationController.toolbar = YES`, the correct would be `self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES`.
The default behavior of a viewController inside of a navigationController is to be resized when you hide the toolbar, you don't need to change the view's frame.

I've just made a test:

```
//before: <UIView: 0x71bdbc0; frame = (0 0; 320 416);...

self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;

//after: <UIView: 0x71bdbc0; frame = (0 0; 320 460);....
```